# How we can implement Magic Link in dot net with blazor application?

Tags: .net, email, jwt, blazor

I want to implement magic-link functionality in my blazor application(the API is in .net core). I  want to create a magic link and then send this magic link in email. By clicking this magic link user will directly enter my application. I am using JWT in our application.

I have no idea how we can achieve this, please help to implement this.

Comment: Will anyone help me to achieve this?